# How to integrate GitHub with Visual Studio 2008 so that source codes can be stored online?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2008, github, github-for-windows

I have istalled and integrated `GitExtensions-2.48.05-SetupComplete.msi`, and, `GitSccProvider.msi` with `Visual Studio 2008`.

[image] 
[image]

As, you can see, plug-ins are working properly.

But, I am not being able to link VS2008 with Github so that I can upload source codes online.

How to integrate GitHub with Visual Studio 2008 so that source codes can be directly stored online?

Comment: this questions is off topic: it has nothing to do with programming. However you've installed 3 different products and yes Git is not the same as GitHub. GitHub leverages Git and introduces a lot of features to help developers code together as a team. Git is the VCS technology that GitHub uses.

Comment: @bitoiu, where should I ask this ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

(1) you have installed a GUI for git named GitExtensions and also git of course and also a git provider for visual studio (which is redundant). Github is an online service to store your repository but to confuse people they also develop a git GUI named 'github for Windows' which goal is to be easy to use.

(2) in the '.git' folder,  in the working directory.

(3) You could use github, as you name it but also bitbucket, visual studio online, gitlab,... Github is the most used and it's where things happen at the moment and they have some good doc to better answer this last point...